# How get multiple values lua?

Tags: lua, numbers, return

**Hello, I'm new in lua and I wonder if it is possible print "from" "to" numbers**

`Ex: Numbers 1 and 3`

`Print 1, 2, 3`

Comment: There are plenty of lua tutorials online. Just about any of them would have answered the question I assume you are asking; which is how to loop over a range of numbers and print them out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no or minimal understanding of fundamental language features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to use [the `for` loop](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html).

```
local iFrom, iTo, iStep = 1, 3, 1
for i = iFrom, iTo, iStep do
    print( i )
end
```